# What order does a For Each Next loop through my checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, foreach

I have about 20 Check Boxes laid out in a rectangle. How do I know what order my code loops through them with a For Each loop?

I've already confirmed it is not in the order of CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3 etc.

Comment: What's your code look like?  You can use `F8` to step through your macro, to see what order it is (can you use something like `checkBox.Select`?). I think by default it'll be in the order added to the workbook.

Comment: You can look at the tab index in design mode

Comment: I can see what order it's going in I just don't know what property is driving that.
@BruceWayne, any idea on how I can change the order if it is in the order they were added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ActiveX checkbox controls laid out on the worksheet, the *<right-click>*, Order command sets the order they are retrieved in a For ... Each loop. The caveat is that the commands seem to be backwards.

[image: checkbox_order]

1. **[Bring to Front](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861432.aspx)** will place the shape object at the tail end of the For Each queue.
2. **[Send to Back](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861432.aspx)** will bring the shape object to the front of the For Each queue.
3. **[Bring Forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861432.aspx)** will shuffle the shape object back one place in the queue.
4. **[Send Backward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861432.aspx)** will push the shape object forward one place in the queue.

The VBA for this is in the [Shape.ZOrder method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840191.aspx).

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Shapes("CheckBox2").ZOrder msoBringForward  '<~~ send back one place in the queue
    .Shapes("CheckBox2").ZOrder msoSendToBack  '<~~ place at the beginning of the queue
End With
```

Use the [Shape.ZOrderPosition property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837628.aspx) to determine the current position.

Comment: Wow! How did you know that?

Comment: Any form controls I use are typically laid out directly on the worksheet. I remember this oddity (reversed direction) when I was trying to set up a cascade of checkboxes where each depended on the state of the previous. There were a lot of checkboxes and I had to figure out how to do it in a loop. I actually spent a fair bit of time working on an 'end one' wondering 'why doesn't this work' until I tried a middle one and figured out that they were reversing the instructions. The ZOrder direction they take probably makes sense to someone but not me.